# JSON file to Redshift using JSONPATHS file - Invalid jsonpath format

Tags: json, amazon-redshift

Trying to load JSON file from s3 into Redshift using Copy with JSONPATHS file. The file contains N number of records.

Loading the entire set in one go throws an error:

**Invalid operation: Invalid JSONPath format. Supported notations are 'dot-notation' and 'bracket-notation'**

The Json paths:

```
{"jsonpaths":
[
    "$.item[:].col1",
    "$.item[:].col2",
    "$.item[:].col3"
]
}
```

sample file:

```
{"item":
[
  {
    "col1":"A",
    "col2":"b",
    "col3":"d"
  },
  {
    "col1": "123",
    "col2": "red",
    "col3": "456"
  }
]
}
```

Working FILE:-

```
 {"jsonpaths":
[
    "$.item[0].col1",
    "$.item[0].col2",
    "$.item[0].col3"
]
}
```

What am I doing wrong to cause this error?

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-usage_notes-copy-from-json.html), there are 2 ways of specifying the JSONPaths. One is to use the dot notation and another is to use the bracket notation.

In this example, the user has used the dot notation, but the arrays have been indexed using a colon (:). The correct way to index JSON arrays elements is to use a number. Hence the second example of the JSONPath file works.